# gdb terminated after info registers

Tags: windows, gdb

I debugging .exe program made of C language by using gdb.

The problem is after I run the command `(gdb) info registers`, gdb just terminated.

I use windows 10. I run gdb on powershell, command prompt. I also run these as administrator. But gdb still exited after I run `info registers` command.

It works fine when I specified register like `info registers eax`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be fixed in GDB 8.2. See bug https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=26304 which is duplicate of https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=22854. Bug 22854 has Target Milestone 8.2 so it was fixed in 8.2 release. I'd suggest to update GDB to at least 8.2 version.

Comment: Thanks! It helps me a lot :)